# Javascript stops running after the page is polled

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am creating a web page using primefaces and I have a script embedded so that I can toggle rows. In the page I also have a poll to update the contents of the page. When the page is first loaded the script runs perfectly, however once the page polls itself to update the contents the script stops working.

The script is from another stackoverflow post and I have no experience in javascript so I am not sure what part is causing this issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        rowExpansion(PF('dtbl'));
    });

    function rowExpansion(dataTable) {
        //dataTable should be the widgetVar object
        var $this = dataTable;
        //add the 'hand' when hovering on row
        $this.tbody.children('tr').css('cursor', 'pointer')
        $this.tbody.off('click.datatable-expansion', '> tr')
        .on('click.datatable-expansion', '> tr', null, function() {
            //toggle the current row the old toggler
            $this.toggleExpansion($(this).find('div.ui-row-toggler'));
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You only call the method in the onReady function. You need to have an event triggered (like, say, a button click) where you call the method again. If you enter the JS console on that webpage you should be able to call the method and have it run. The issue is that you aren't calling it again anywhere.

Comment: When you say "once the page polls itself" what does that mean? can you show that code? is it refreshing the page?

Comment: Embedding a script to be able to toggle rows in general or to open all the moment the page is renderd?

Comment: @AndrewLohr yes, sorry. The poll is just a tag that calls some action in the controller on some set interval. In my case it is updating the page.

Comment: @AdamS I need the script to be running continually so that the mouse can click on the rows. The script adds the ability to click on the rows to trigger a row expansion rather than having to use the toggler component primefaces provides. Is there some function that is called when a page is refreshed or on a continuous basis that would be more appropriate for what I am trying to do? I don't want someone to have to click to get the script back and running again.

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry I didn't explain the script well enough. The purpose of the script is to add the functionality for the user to be able to click anywhere on a table row to trigger a row expansion rather than having to click on a button. Ideally this script should be running nonstop so that the user never loses this functionality.

Comment: Then 'just' re-run it on each datatable ajax request in the oncomplete

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you very much, that solved my issue. I'm still new to this so your help was much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. Please create an answer how you actually solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the advice given by @Kukeltje and @AdamS  I fixed this issue by calling the function in the script at oncomplete in my poll object. The script was only being called at the page initialization and needed to be recalled whenever the poll was triggered. Was previously...

```
<p:poll interval="30" listener="#{dashboardBean.update}" update="reporttbl"/>
```

and is now...

```
<p:poll interval="30" listener="#{dashboardBean.update}" update="reporttbl" oncomplete="rowExpansion(PF('dtbl'))" />
```